# How do I add a preceding zero to single digits numbers and concatinate the columns so the date appears in one column

Tags: sql

My query provides the following results:

select year, month, day from table

```
year    month   day
----    -----   ---
1999    10  9
2000    11  14
2003    6   4
2007    9   14
2008    9   30
1999    3   8
1999    5   27
1999    10  19
```

I would like to have my results look like this:

```
date
19991009
20001114
20030604
20070914
20080930
19990308
19990527
19991019
```

Comment: Always try to include your rdbms tag for sql questions `SqlServer`, `MySql`?. Some functions arent available on all databases.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is more from the point of view of MS sql server since I don't know which rdbms you are using:

```
select cast(year as varchar(10)) + right('00' +cast(month as varchar(10)),2) + right('00' +cast(day as varchar(10)),2)
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you data is already string you can use

```
SELECT year +
       RIGHT('00'+ month, 2) + 
       RIGHT('00'+ day, 2)
```

For integer something like this

```
SELECT 
      CAST(year AS VARCHAR(4))+
      RIGHT('00'+ CAST(month AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + 
      RIGHT('00'+ CAST(day AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
FROM YourTable
```

For integer this also may work

```
SELECT 
      CAST(year AS VARCHAR(4))+
      RIGHT(100 + month, 2) + 
      RIGHT(100 + day, 2)
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
SELECT CAST(year AS varchar) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(month AS varchar),2) + RIGHT('0'+ CAST(day AS varchar),2) 
FROM Table
```